# Capture a snapshot of an upploaded video and save image.png file - JQUERY

Tags: jquery, image, video, snapshot

I need to capture a snapshot of an upploaded video and save .png file to mysql database along with other form info. A User doenst need to click on "capture" bottom - the process of it will work at background. I think, it's managable ro do with pure jquery. Can you give me a drift of an idea of how to do that?

If you guyz will get my problem better - I need to make something similar to Youtube type of capturing snaps. If you've ever took a time to look how youtube displays videos - you've seen that all of them are just images embedded in links appart from actual video that you want to watch. Im making a video-watch website and I dont want to load 10-20 videos on a single page -so There would be only one video and others - images to it - exactely this image I need somehow to get!

Code: (upploaded video)

```
 echo '<video  class="video" controls> <source src="'.$result[0].'" type="video/mp4"> </video>';
```

I think there is no need to post php uppload video and form file.
PLease, let me know if anyone has any ideas. So: I need a video url and and image url in my database and video and an image to it itself in their own folders (temp_video and temp_image). Right now I have only a video url in database and the video in the temp_video folder. Yes, I know, That I'll need to create an additional column in db and a folder in root and I know hoe to do that. What I dont know is how exactely to capture a snapshot of a 'here-is-a-video' and get the name of it - so I can save it to the folder and manipulate it further.

Many thanks in advance.

PS. Idealy I'd want to have a jquery (fiddle) code, that captures a snapshot and displays it, but just the right idea would be also nice. Again - only Jquery code needed and the ability to get the image by its name, I can do the rest of the stuff.Many thanks who will help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create 'thumbnail' images or 'box art' images for your videos.

Given the videos are already on your server from the description you outlined, I think you probably want to create the thumbnails on the server side rather than the client side - I am guessing you were thinking of doing this on the client side based on your question.

You could still tie this in to the client side by getting your client, via JQuery for example, to make a request to the server asking it to generate a thumbnail for a given video that you are displaying at the moment, but most solutions will generate the thumbnails in advance to reduce real time server load and to avoid repeating the work every time you need to display a video thumbnail. Note, that if you have a very large video library, with only a small percentage likely to be viewed then it might make more sense to do it when requested, but this would be an atypical example.

I'm not sure what server side technology you are using, but you mention PHP so here is an example PHP library to generate thumbnails:

- https://github.com/kylegilman/video-embed-thumbnail-generator/blob/master/video-embed-thumbnail-generator.php

If you are using nodeJS on the server side then here is a node example:

- https://github.com/vdemedes/thumbbot

Most libraries will use FFMPEG one way or another so you could also find a library for your server technology that provides an interface into FFMPEG - for example for node again:

- https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg